# why not picking native windows cache?

Tags: kerberos, jaas

looking at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/AcnOnly.html

```
LoginContext lc = null;
    try {
        lc = new LoginContext("JaasSample", new TextCallbackHandler());
    } catch (LoginException le) {
        System.err.println("Cannot create LoginContext. "
            + le.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        System.err.println("Cannot create LoginContext. "
            + se.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    try {

      // attempt authentication
      lc.login();

  } catch (LoginException le) {

      System.err.println("Authentication failed: "
      System.err.println("  " + le.getMessage());
      System.exit(-1);

  }

  System.out.println("Authentication succeeded!");

}

my config file :-

   JaasSample {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    debug=true
    doNotPrompt=true 
    useTicketCache=true
         ;
    };
```

why does it not use the cache of the windows user that has signed on?
Have I misunderstood?

thanks in advance?
JemRug

Comment: Why not add Jaas config to point to the ticket cache you think it should be using?  (It could be misconfigured)

Comment: The reason I know it can't find in memory , the user get prompted for principle(which is defaults as jemrug@test.rug) and windows password via the TextCallBackHandler,  For Windows native cache, I don't know where it stores it, I'm thinking it holds it in memory as I am unable to find it?